# SQL select default parameter

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns like name, age, email etc. For some columns I also have parameters to control the behaviour of queries. I want to show the column's value if the corresponding parameter has the value 0. If that parameter has value 1 I don’t want to show that column.

For example, if I have data

```
name  age  show_email  email
abc,  22   1           abc@gmail.com  -- parameter = 1 do not show this value
def,  33   0           def@gmail.com  -- parameter = 0 => show this value
```

Then output of `select name, age, email from MyTable1` will be

```
name  age  email
abc,  22   NULL          -- NULL because of parameter value.
def,  33   def@gmail.com
```

Comment: You're looking for one of the [control flow functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the case statement

```
select name, age,
 case show_email when 0 then email else null end
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, age,
       IF(show_email, email, NULL) AS email
    from my_table;
```